# How to get CSS file with WebMvcConfigurer in Spring

Tags: html, css, spring

I will show you my code and project structure then what I tried so far:

`WebMvcConfigurer:`

```
    @Configuration
public class ResourceHandlers implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/*").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
    }
}
```

This is in my `.jsp` page: `<spring:url value="/resources/css/homepage.css" var="homePageCss" />`

This is my project strucutre:

```
.idea
 .lib
 -src
   -main
     .java
     - resources //this is automatically created folder resources
       - css
         - homepage
           .homepage.css
     -webapp
      - resources
        - css
          - homepage
            .homepage.css
```

In this project structure that I showed I tried both ways. Manually create `resource` folder inside `webapp` and then create folder `css`, `homepage`, and then `css` page.

Also I tried to create `css`, `homepage` and the `css` page inside my automatically created folder resources but both ways doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Also add @EnableWebMvc Annotation

Try This

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/homepage/");  
}
```

JSP

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%> //Add at the top the page
   <%@page isELIgnored="false"%> //Add at the top the page

 <spring:url value="/resources/homepage.css" var="homePageCss" />
  <link href="${homePageCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
```